# RSS feed does not validate on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss, feedburner

I have an error message when I click on my site's rss feed url (both from feedburner and the original atom feed):

"This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

I Have check with The rss feed validator and this is what I got:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FNoCamels

I tried everything they suggested (also restarted the plugins) - but nothing worked.

PLEASE, I need your help!

Yuval

Comment: do you use the default rss feeds? You can make sure by checking them with a clean install without theme's/plugins in a subdirectory or local

Comment: I tried to use also the default rss feed - same message: http://nocamels.com/feed/

How can I test it on clean install - it is a working site... should I switch to the default WP theme and check it? Got any idea from the error I attached?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a blank line outside php tags in your wordpress files.

You should check and remove blank lines in :

- wp-config.php
- functions.php of your theme
- *.php in your plugins
- ...etc

Take a look here :
http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2009/05/wordpress-feed-xml-parsing-errors/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The culprit was the wp-trackback.php. Blank space at the bottom. I cleared the blank space and voila. RSS is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have also this question. I solved from [error on line 2 at column 6](http://www.gogorapid.com/how-to-fix-xml-site-map/)

You simply have a blank line outside php tags in your WordPress files.

You should check and remove blank lines in :

wp-config.php
functions.php of your theme
*.php in your plugins
...etc
Take a look here